# how to Zoom to specific markers react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

how to Zoom to specific markers react-native-maps

like this image
[image: map image]

Answer (score 2):

First create a ref to the MapView component:

```js
        <MapView
          ref={ref => {
            this.map = ref;
          }}
          ...
        >
          ...
        </MapView>
```

Then use one of the following three methods:

- fitToElements - focus on all markers
- fitToSuppliedMarkers - focus on specific markers by ID - [example from docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/FitToSuppliedMarkers.js).
- fitToCoordinates - focus on a set of coordinates - [example from docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/FitToCoordinates.js).

You can find more details on these methods and parameters in the [MapView docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md).

Answer (score 0):

You can use onPress or onSelect props of marker which accepts a callback function where you can pass the zooom size of marker. I hope it is useful